# FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SendGrid, Version=9.11.0.0

Tags: asp.net

I'm working with Asp.net core, but I'm not sure if the problem is with this. I'm having this error with libraries deploying the application to Windows Server. I checked and the required dll's are there. This bug is with new libraries for some moment, not only SendGrid. The application works fine on my desktop.

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SendGrid, Version=9.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4f047e93159395ca'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
```

Comment: Only to confirm that file is there: PS C:\WebApplications\Transporte> ([system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile("c:\WebApplications\Transporte\SendGrid.dll"))
.FullName
SendGrid, Version=9.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4f047e93159395ca

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. File Trsnaporte.deps.json was out of date.